# what happens to symbolic or soft links when you store the filename within the inode?

Tags: file, directory, operating-system

I understand that the whole reason that you do not store the file name within the inode is so that you can use a hard link to point to the inode's number. But in terms of symbolic links, they use the file name in order to access the file rather than the i-number. So would they be accessible to point to a file name that is written within the i-node already?

Answer (score 0):

Hard links only work within the same disk.

In order to work across disks, soft links point to a file name that in turn [may] point to an inode.

Answer (score 0):

symlinks don't point to files, they are just a bunch of bytes which can replace symlink's own name during lookup.

That is, if 'foo' is a symlink to 'bar', looking up 'foo/crap' will end up looking up 'bar/crap'.

It is trivial to construct examples where following a symlink makes you end up with different files. For instance one can [chroot(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html) somewhere and then follow a symlink which is either absolute or has several '..'s. Let's say the symlink is named 'crap', contains "/meh" and placed is /mycontainer. Then processes which chroot to /mycontainer and follow 'crap', will end up on /mycontainer/crap from "outside" perspective. Meanwhile processes which did not chroot will end up on /crap.